# Why does browser convert single quotes to double doing an AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

Jquery:

```
var val = "<!DOCTYPE html><html lang='en'><head><meta charset='utf-8'><meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'><title>test title</title><link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'></head><body style='background:#e9e9e9;'>{other html content goes here}</body></html>";
var params = escape(val);
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    url: 'http://mylocalapilink/api/test',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        'sub': 'test',
        'msg': params
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function () {

    }
});
```

When I run the above I get this error in console: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

When i check the source of the error, I see this (https://pasteboard.co/GPwutqg.png):

[image]

The goal is to send the entire HTML back to the Web API.

How can I go around it if possible. Thanks.

Comment: See what? I can't see any images, is there any text.information in the image that could be copied into the question to ensure that when the image link is broken or unavailable the question still makes sense?

Comment: Sorry added a link: https://pasteboard.co/GPwutqg.png. I didn't know it wasn't showing up. Weird, I can see it.

Comment: Putting HTML inside JavaScript can be tricky because the HTML parser doesn’t know anything about JavaScript. At it sees is open and closing tags. You might have to break up the markup in the string to not confuse the HTML parser.

Comment: Any idea on how I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using escaping `"` characters like `\"`

```
var val = "<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=\"en\"><meta charset=\"utf-8\"http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=edge\"></head><body style=\"background:#e9e9e9;\">{other html content goes here}</body></html>";
var params = escape(val);
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    url: 'http://mylocalapilink/api/test',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        'sub': 'test',
        'msg': params
    },
    success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    },
    error: function () {

    }
});
```

Comment: I get this error now: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

Comment: Even though the HTML in one line, when i check the source as shown above, it is broken up into three separate lines in console... no idea why